# Creating predictions from a time series model

Tags: r, time-series

I have created an ARIMA model and am trying to plot but I can't get my predictions right. I have data over a week in a number of locations, i now wish to fit a time series model to predict the maximum temperature in one of my locations, however my predictions only give me one mean value rather than a weeks worth to fit a time series which is what i am after. So therefore when i attempt to plot this i get a blank plot.

Data and code below

```
nov_data$Yeovilton
17.3 16.5 11.1 10.7 12.0 12.9 14.8


arima_mod = arima(nov_data$Yeovilton, order = c(1,1,1))

#creating predictions
forecast2 = predict(arima_mod)

#plot
plot(forecast2$pred, main = 'Model predictions', xlab = 'Day', ylab = 'Temperature °C')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, here is the solution:

```
library(forecast)
nov_data=c(17.3,16.5,11.1,10.7,12.0,12.9,14.8)

arima_mod <- arima(nov_data, order = c(1,1,1))

forecast2 <- forecast(arima_mod,7)


plot(forecast2,main = 'Model predictions', xlab = 'Day', ylab = 'Temperature °C')
```

Comment: Just been testing this, i think im not trying to predict into the future, im trying to predict over data that i already have. So i basically want that plot without the forecast part if that makes sense. (could be a wider issue here of me too little data so its just going to predict observed values anyway)